# WYSIWYG editor for multimarkdown?

Tags: javascript, html, editor, wysiwyg, multimarkdown

I was looking at MultiMarkdown just a bit ago, a subset of Markdown which adds some extra features (such as tables).  Is anyone aware if there are any WYSIWYG editors for Multimarkdown, and if they can be embedded into an HTML page?

**PS:** I am already aware of this question already, but it only covers editors for Markdown, not MultiMarkdown: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4843649/wysiwyg-edit-with-markdown-output

Comment: I don't know Multimarkdown but I made a serious attempt to make HTML to Markdown converter and I strongly recommend to avoid this "challenge". Markdown has no specification, there are no 1:1 transformations for some HTML constructs (I'm of course talking about HTML limited to features available in MD) and every MD2HTML converter which I checked worked differently in details. So if you want stable solution then use HTML.